# I can't debbug my php application running in a docker container on my linux machine with Xdebug using Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, linux, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to set up an development environment with docker to run an CakePHP application and debbug it using Xdebug. Aparentely, Xdebug configuration is alright, but it can't connect back to my IDE either because of some misconfiguration of my lauch.json or because of the `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal` directive in my xdebug.ini that may not  be working properly in my Linux machine, even after I putted `RUN ip -4 route list match 0/0 | awk '{print $3 " host.docker.internal"}' >> /etc/hosts` in my dockerfile, but the result of this command is never an entry mapping to host.docker.internal, instead it returns a series of numbers like so: `172.26.0.3      24577f456543`
.

I already tried to put the ip address of my linux machine witch is hosting the docker container on the `xdebug.remote_host` directive in xdebug.ini, but it still didin't work. Unfortunetelly I couldn't get the `xdebug.remote_log' working as well, witch may be a sign that I can be doing something wrong in that point too.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

USER root

#####################################
# Non-Root User:
#####################################

# Add a non-root user to prevent files being created with root permissions on host machine.
ARG PUID=1000
ARG PGID=1000

ENV PUID ${PUID}
ENV PGID ${PGID}

RUN groupadd -g ${PGID} ubuntu && \
    useradd -u ${PUID} -g ubuntu -m ubuntu && \
    apt-get update -yqq

# RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    # add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php

# PHP 5 AND EXTENSIONS INSTALL
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        php5-cli \
        php5-common \
        php5-curl \
        php5-json \
        # php5-xml \
        # php5-mbstring \
        php5-mcrypt \
        php5-mysql \
        # php5-sqlite3 \
        # php5-zip \
        # php5-bcmath \
        php5-gd \
        php5-dev \
        pkg-config \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libedit-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        xz-utils \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        git \
        curl \
        vim \
        nano \
    && apt-get clean

# APACHE2 AND APACHE_PHP 5 INSTALL with rewrite enabled
RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get install -yqq --force-yes \
        apache2 \
        libapache2-mod-php5 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && a2enmod rewrite

# ENABLE MCRYPT
RUN php5enmod mcrypt

# Source the bash
RUN . ~/.bashrc

# ADD DEFAULT VHOST
COPY ./docker/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

#####################################
# xDebug:
#####################################
USER root

RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes php5-xdebug && \
    sed -i 's/^;//g' /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini && \
    echo "alias phpunit='php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit'" >> ~/.bashrc 

RUN ip -4 route list match 0/0 | awk '{print $3 " host.docker.internal"}' >> /etc/hosts

# ADD for REMOTE debugging
COPY ./docker/xdebug.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini

#####################################
# NODE INSTALL:
#####################################
USER ubuntu

# Check if NVM needs to be installed
ARG NODE_VERSION=6.9
ENV NVM_DIR /home/ubuntu/.nvm

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash && \
        . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && \
        nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} && \
        nvm use ${NODE_VERSION} && \
        nvm alias ${NODE_VERSION} 

# Wouldn't execute when added to the RUN statement in the above block
# Source NVM when loading bash since ~/.profile isn't loaded on non-login shell
RUN echo "" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm' >> ~/.bashrc 

# Add NVM binaries to root's .bashrc
USER root

RUN echo "" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo 'export NVM_DIR="/home/ubuntu/.nvm"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm' >> ~/.bashrc 

#####################################
# TESSERACT INSTALL:
#####################################

RUN apt-get install tesseract-ocr -y

# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

# Set default work directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

**xdebug.ini:**

```
; Defaults
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

; The Linux way
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1

; idekey value is specific to Visual Studio Code
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE

; Optional: Set to true to always auto-start xdebug
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  smarty-center:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - mysql56:mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    container_name: app
    networks:
      - homologacao-network
    depends_on:
      - mysql56
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=nopass
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - mysql56:db
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - homologacao-network
    depends_on:
      - mysql56
  mysql56:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=nopass
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: mysql56
    networks:
      - homologacao-network
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
networks:
  homologacao-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**lauch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Xdebug for Project smarty center",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9001
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect Xdebug working properly to debbug my application running in a container.

Comment: Have you enabled port 9001 for your docker container?

Comment: You mean to expose port 9001? If that's what you mean I saw that it's not necessary and if I do this I will block Xdebug to connect back to my IDE (witch I forgot to specify, but is VS code)